# Best way to compare Time only between different Time Zones

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

I'm currently working on a project that requires a user (in their respective time zone) to set a 'cut off' time for certain Notifications that they receive throughout the day. The user will, for instance, say they want no alerts prior to 8:00 AM and no later than 7:30 PM. This user is located in CST (the time zone information for each user is saved) and the 'server' is in EST. The server is where all of the logical decisions occur for which user should be notified, etc.

What would be the best practice to convert the time part only for comparison purposes?

My current thought would be to take the time set by the user, say "7:00 AM", and create a full DateTime object and store that as .ToUniversalTime(). On the server I can convert the DateTime object to Local time and compare the Time portion only.

Does anyone have a 'better' solution or possibly any advice from someone who has tackled a similar issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Best way is to convert it to UTC then  compare

Comment: I would say you're on the right track, but it's better practice to do your conversion to UTC time (rather than to local time) and compare against UTC time.

Comment: .ToUniversalTime() does convert to GMT/UTC. Not sure the point of the previous to comments. I'd convert to the server's local time though, as that would simplify things.

Comment: Here's a cool date/time library I'm fond of, maybe it will help with portions of your project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Comment: You are storing the dates as UTC, good start. Given the times are *local* you want to convert back to local *then* compare. I implemented something similar to this a while back and this is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you store the minimum time and maximum time as local times, without dates. You will also want to store the users general timezone information, for example "Central Time", not CST or CDT.

When you are ready to make a determination about sending a notification, convert the current UTC time to the user's local timezone and compare the stored time range against the converted time.

Trying to create a full calendar date from stored time information will be problematic in certain cases, specifically for daylight savings changes. By converting from UTC to user's local time for the comparison, that problem will be avoided.